# How do I test for an empty Address webform element?

Tags: theming, webforms, tokens

Using Drupal 9.1.3 : Webform 6.0.0

How to check for the null value of a Webform Address Composite element

```
{% if webform_token('[webform_submission:values:**ELEMENT_NAME**]', webform_submission, [], options) **????**%}
```

I have tried the following without finding the correct statement.

```
{% if webform_token(...)  is same as(null) %}
```

```
{% if webform_token(...) is null %}
```

```
{% if webform_token(...) is empty %}
```

```
{% if webform_token(...) == '' %}
```

```
(...) = ('[webform_submission:values:address]', webform_submission, [], options)
```

The only output I get from all 4 statements is:

```
[webform_submission:values:address]
```